# I don't know why I am receiving error CS1061

Tags: c#

I am working on an id tester. I get error CS1061 every second.
This is my code:

```
Process[]roblox=Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe");
Console.WriteLine("Id of RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is:", roblox.Id);
int id = roblox.Id;
```

Comment: I know why you're getting it, but in all seriousness I'll write an answer

Comment: obviously, share the whole error message

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre good answer!

Comment: Forker, you need to actually ask a precise question!

Comment: @MarcusMüller it was a joke - as I'm sure you're aware

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre fully :) as was my sarcastic remark

Comment: Believe it or not, most C# developers don't know what all of the error numbers are by heart.  Please, always put the entire error message in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler Error CS1061 will give you more details on why you get this error. But in your question you haven't include most important part of error details. 
roblox is array, if you need to get id of process then you need to get item in the array. items of array can be access via index

```
Process[]roblox=Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe");

if(roblox!=null && roblox.Length >0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Id of RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is:", roblox[0].Id);
  int id = roblox[0].Id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working finely!

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of processes `roblox`, but try to access the `Id` property of the entire thing as opposed to well... a process. In order to fix this you must actually select the index you wish to use the `Id` of

```
Process[] roblox = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe");
if(roblox.GetLength(0) > 0) //Check that any processes exist with that name
{
    int id = roblox[0].Id; //set ID first as to avoid accessing the array twice
    Console.WriteLine("Id of RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is:" + id); //Write the line using the newly found id variable
}
else //If the process doesn't exist
{
    Console.WriteLine("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is not running"); //Output error of sorts
}
```

Also fixed here is your `Console.WriteLine()`, the way you're using it would require a parameter like this `Console.WriteLine("Id of RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is:{0}", id);` or use concatenation like I do in the example. You seem to have attempted a mixture of the two, which doesn't work

If you are having any issues with getting to grips with arrays, have a read [of this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

To paraphrase it, regarding the issue you had, once you have an array, for example

```
string[] stringArray = new string[] {"hello", "hi"};
```

You can access its contained objects like so

```
string firstIndex = stringArray[0]; //for the first index
string secondIndex = stringArray[1]; //for the second index
```

If we were then to write this

```
Console.WriteLine(firstIndex + secondIndex);
```

It would output `hellohi`

As a side note, you are receiving error **CS1061** specifically because you are trying to access a property of the array which does not exist

**NB:** An interesting one-liner, using `-1` to indicate the process is not running

```
int id = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe")?[0].Id ?? -1;
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working finely! Very good Explaining!

Comment: @ForkerGup Additionally if you would prefer to do it how you did by accessing the properties directly, instead of `Process[] roblox = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe");`, you can do `Process roblox = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe")?[0];`. This code will set the Process to the roblox process, or it will set it to null if that process is not running